# Use two data tables in one form

Tags: c#, forms, database-connection, localdb

I'm trying to implement a parent-child form which contains results from two data tables. I need the child table data to change when I navigate through the parent form records.

[image]

In my scenario, I need to change transaction records with the user table.

I tried adding it as a SQL query. It works fine if I use the 'User' table in the query itself, but when I use 'transaction' or any other table, it gives a syntax error.

> Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRANSACTION'.

```
private void Tester_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.transactionDBDataSet.Customer);
    bindTransactionData();
}

private void bindTransactionData() {
    string query = "SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    transactionGridView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: `TRANSACTION` is a SQL reserved word, if you want it to refer to a table instead of a command you must surround it with brackets like `[TRANSACTION]`. You probably also want to use actual column names instead of `*`, and `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses in that SQL.

Comment: That was the exact issue. Thanks @DourHighArch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word 'TRANSACTION' is reserved.  In SQL Server, this would need to be qualified with brackets, so your SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [TRANSACTION]
```

You're not using SQL Server, but I bet this still solves your issue as this is a fairly standard practice.

Comment: That was the exact issue. Thanks @CodeHxr